# licenses.licx in Class Library vs Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not quite sure how to ask this questions, so please forgive me for my ignorance.

I have a ASP.NET Web Application and I have as part of this solution a Project that contains all my library of functions and such.  So, for simple explanation, I have two projects in one solution.  One is a WEB Application and the other is a Project that gets compiled as a DLL and used within the WEB Application.

Inside my Library, I use GrapeCity Active Reports and a few other libraries that I have purchased and licensed.  I have created references in my Library and I call those functions to generate reports and stream them.  The WEB Application knows nothing about these controls, how they work or anything.  So, lets say I call a function GetReport() that will generate the report and stream out to the client as a PDF.

My Library has the LICENSES.LICX with all the necessary license information in it.

The question is this.  Do I have to include the license information in the ASP.NET Application, or will it become part of the DLL and I don't have to worry about the ASP.NET Application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know the caller assembly/exe of the component should have license embed to it you can refer to [this link](https://www.textcontrol.com/blog/2009/10/15/net-licensing-how-to-use-the-licenseslicx-file/) or [this link](https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/licensing-problems-the-licenses-licx-file-and-you) that show and tell you more about it.